# Mock a client to a dependency when doing integration tests

Tags: testing, mocking, microservices

I have a service composed of several micro services working in workflow. Some of these MS are calling dependencies.
Now I'd like to mock these calls, so when I send a message at the entrance of the workflow the dependencies answers get mocked, but my system works as normal.

The challenge is that I would want to configure the mock from the outside: Configure on the fly the answer I want to get from the mock, run my test, verify that my system behaves properly.

I worked for a company that shall remain unnamed that has an internal tool doing just that, but I'm wondering if there is a public tool doing this? I can't believe it doesn't exist, I bet more on my lack of knowledge about this, at that point ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So far best I've found is https://wiremock.org/docs/
I don't want to do any ad here, it's just the only one I see that gets its mocks configured from a distance

Comment: Wiremock is excellent and used by many for exactly this sort of testing. I'd also like to point out that if you need to test compatibility between your own microservices (if they communicate over REST), you should have a look at CDCT using Pact.